# Changing the z-coordinate of one of vertex in Polyline3d

Tags: c#, 3d, autocad, polyline, vertex

Please somebody help. Why it does not work?
I have Polyline3d in AutoCAD and the target coordinations to move one of vertex on it. But is does not work. No error, all is clear. But vertex does not move to target pozition. Where am i mistake?

```
private void MoveOneVertex(Polyline3d poly3d, Point3d old_pozition, Point3d new_pozition)
        {
            Document doc = AuAcApSerApp.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
            Database db  = doc.Database;
            Editor   edt = doc.Editor;           

            using (var trans = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    //Sorting through all vertexes of polyline
                    ObjectId[] verts = poly3d.Cast<ObjectId>().ToArray();

                    for (int i = 0; i < verts.Length; i++)
                    {
                        PolylineVertex3d vertex = trans.GetObject(verts[i], OpenMode.ForWrite) as PolylineVertex3d;

                        if (vertex.Position == old_pozition)
                        {                           
                            vertex.Position = new_pozition; //moving vertex to new pozition                                                     
                        } 
                    }

                    trans.Commit();
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    edt.WriteMessage("\nError encountered " + ex.Message);
                    trans.Abort();
                }
            }           
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose condition `if (vertex.Position == old_pozition)` is a problem.

try this:

```
double PRECISION = 0.000001; // or other precision as You need
if ( vertex.Position.DistanceTo(old_pozition) < PRECISION)
```

You passed the polyline as a parameter but is the polyline open for writing somewhere before?

```
Polyline3d poly3d = tr.GetObject(res.ObjectId , OpenMode.ForWrite) as Polyline3d;
```

Comment: Thanks for you! But it does not help me. Unfortunately the reasons in somethings else... I check in real code that the condition is met.

Comment: is the polyline open for writing before

Comment: Good. I found the problem. In the dialog form. It did "return" after the grafics was completed. I have solved this problem.
But now a new problem has arisen. The vertexes was moved. But on the screen, the polyline looks the same as before. And the polyline moved to a new location only after saving/opening the drawing.

Comment: This is not discussion forum. If You met new problem, ask new question. By the way, if my answer helped you, it would be nice to upvote or accept the anwer. This will give me reputation poins and here on stackoverflow we like reputation. It makes us more eager to next responses. 
By the way do You Commit the transaction when the work is complete?